# Linq Query for Corresponding SQL

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Below is my SQL Statement, I am Unable to Convert to LINQ

```
select o.CustId,c.CustName,Count(o.CustId) as Total_Orders from Customer c 
inner join Orders o on c.CustId = o.CustId group by o.CustId,c.CustName
```

Comment: [Group by](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386922.aspx) using linq.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
var query = db.Customers.Select(c => new 
                {
                    CustId = c.CustId,
                    CustName = c.CustName,
                    Total_Orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.CustId == c.CustId).Count()
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
    var query = from c in Customer
            join o in Orders 
            on c.CustId 
            equals o.CustId 
            group x by new {o.CustId, c.CustName} 
            into g
                select new 
                {
                  g.Key.CustId,
                  g.Key.CustName,
                  Total_Orders = g.Count()
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the LINQ query (`db` is EntityFramework [DBContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)).

```
var query =  from c in db.Customers
             join o in db.Orders on c.CustId equals o.CustId into g
             groupby new { CustID = c.CustId, CustName=c.CustName } into gs
             select new { CustID = gs.Key.CustId, CustName=gs.Key.CustName, Count= gs.Count() } into gs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from c in context.Customers
            select new
            {
                c.CustId,
                c.CustName,
                Orders = c.Orders.Count(),
            };
```